# Why does PyTorch dataloader require each element in the batch size to be the same?

Tags: pytorch

Otherwise you get this error: "RuntimeError: each element in list of batch should be of equal size"

Can someone explain why it's enforced?

Answer (score 0):

In `collate_fn()` of dataloader, each element returned from `__getitem__()` function is simply stacked up themselves.

For example; tensors with a different shape cannot be stacked or concatenated with `torch.stack()` or `torch.cat()`.

Answer (score 0):

A dataloader basically concatenates the items in a batch into one tensor. Lets say the items in your batch are of size N x M and you have batch size K, the input to the model becomes K x N x M. Therefore both N and M have to be same for all items.

Sometimes you have variable dimensions in your data, like with Recurrent Neural Networks. In that case you can use batches by doing one of the following:

- Sort your data and pick your batches based on their dimensionality. I.e. you enforce items in your batch to have the same size, but different batches can have different sizes.
- Use padding to 'fill up' the items in your batches that are smaller than the maximum size within your data.